# Why Any $B$-bounded centered random variable $X$ is subgaussian with parameter $B \sqrt{2\pi}$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, cryptography

Definition of subgaussian is below

> A random variable $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is subgaussian with parameter $\alpha > 0$ if its moment generating function satisfies $\mathbb{E}[exp(2 \pi tX)] \leq exp(\pi \alpha^2 t^2)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

And there is a fact about subgaussian.

> Any $B$-bounded centered random variable $X$ is subgaussian with parameter $B \sqrt{2\pi}$.

Why is the parameter $B \sqrt{2\pi}$? I cannot understand above fact.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove first that for a mean zero random variable bounded by $B$,
$$\mathbb{E}[exp(2 \pi tX)] \leq \mathbb{E}[exp(2 \pi tY)]$$
where $Y$ is a random variable with $\mathbb{P}(Y=B)=0.5$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y=-B)=0.5$. proving the theorem for $Y$ is much simpler!